# Custom Segue not working if NOT set as initial window

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Following is the code excerpts for the custom segue animation in Swift, which works fine if I make the source viewController as Initial Window in storyboard, only.

```
class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue
{
    override func perform()
    {
        var fromView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
        var toView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

        let offScreenHorizontalStart = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI / 2))
        let offScreenHorizontalEnd = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI / 2))

        fromView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
        fromView.layer.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: nil, animations:
            {
                fromView.transform = offScreenHorizontalEnd
            }, completion: {
                finished in
                self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

By this segue animation, the source view expects to disappear with an upside rotation from x/y = 0/0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you are using explicitly the `keyWindow` property of the `UIApplication` object here:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)
```

I think it is no surprise that it won't work for other windows.

You could use the `windows` property of `UIApplication` instead. It holds all `UIWindow` objects currently open in the app in an ordered `NSArray` (the last object in the array is the topmost window). 
Or you pick the current window from the `fromView.window` property?

Comment: That seems helpful. Thanks! 

I also seen the following code worked for me!

`var tmpView = firstVCView.superview
tmpView?.insertSubview(secondVCView, belowSubview: firstVCView)`